# Map changed fields by setting new value for a list

Tags: arrays, angular, list, typescript, object

I need to map the fields that have been changed by checking which key of the field was changed and creating a new key with a value that will be shown on the screen to the user.

```
log: [
    0: {type: "Changed", fields_changed: Array(2), date_modification: Timestamp, modified_by: "ID_USER"}
    1: {type: "Changed", fields_changed: Array(4), date_modification: Timestamp, modified_by: "ID_USER"}
    2: {type: "Changed", fields_changed: Array(2), date_modification: Timestamp, modified_by: "ID_USER"}
    3: {type: "Changed", fields_changed: Array(4), date_modification: Timestamp, modified_by: "ID_USER"}
]

fields_changed: [
    0: {key: "name", value: "New name"}
    1: {key: "age", value: 22}
]
```

I need to map it with `fieldsNames` to check the field name and create a new log object to be displayed to the user.

```
const fieldsNames = [
    {key: 'name', field_name: 'Name'},
    {key: 'age', field_name: 'Age'},
]
```

With this I would create a new log list with the field names instead of the field key name.

**Example:**

```
fields_changed: [
    0: {key: "name", value: "New name", field_name: "Nome"}
    1: {key: "age", value: 22, field_name: "Age"}
]
```

For each object I would have a new list inside the `fields_changed` key with a new key named `field_name` so that I can display on the screen for the user the name of the field that was changed.

**With this I would have a new log list with the `fields_changed` list changed as above.**

For the user I want to show which fields have been changed, then I must go through `fields_changed` and get the `field_name` which is a string with the field name.

Comment: Can you explain what a `field` is within the context of your question? If i'd have to fill in the blanks, i'd think you start off with a `FormGroup` and want to create a new log entry when the user submits the form. This log entry will contain an array of fields and values that are different from the initial values in the form.

Comment: I'm also a bit unclear as to the question. Are you just trying to transform the fields_changed array to include another property? Or is there something more to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

If I understood you correcty, this should help you. It creates new log object with `fields_changed` array containing `{key: string, field_name: string, value: string,}` objects.

Here's a working example, I changed your example a little bit for simplicity.

```js
const log = [
    {
        type: "Changed", 
        fields_changed: [
            { key: "name", value: "New name" },
            { key: 'city', value: 'new york' }
        ]
    },
    { 
        type: "Changed", 
        fields_changed: [
            { key: "age", value: '10' }
        ] 
    },
]

const fieldsNames = [
    { key: 'name', field_name: 'Name' },
    { key: 'age', field_name: 'Age' },
    { key: 'city', field_name: 'City' }
]


const changes_for_display = log
    // loop through log object.
    .map(change => ({

        // for every object, map its fields_changed property,
        fields_changed: change.fields_changed.map(field_change => {

            // Look for a field in fieldsNames with same key as field_change.
            const field = fieldsNames.find(name => name.key === field_change.key);
            if (!field) {
                throw 'Field ' + field_change.key + ' NOT FOUND....';
            }

            // build new field_change object out of it,
            // basaically, just asasign value property..
            return Object.assign(field, { value: field_change.value })

        }), type: change.type })
    );


// Cheers..
console.log(changes_for_display)
```

Comment: Very good, that's what I needed ... thank you for your help! Thank you!